# hooks/post-receive: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")

Tags: git, bash

I am writing a post-receive script in GIT.

I attach a minimal version of it, which also fails:

```
generate_email()
{
    for user in $(git config --get-all notifications.users); do
        unset files_to_notify
        for filter in $(git config --get-all notifications.$user); do
            files_to_notify=" $files_to_notify $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id \
                --name-only -r $newrev | grep $filter) "
        done
        files_to_notify=( $files_to_notify )
        if [ -n "$files_to_notify" ]; then
            echo ${files_to_notify[*]}
        fi
    done
}

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    generate_email $oldrev $newrev $refname
done
```

When I'm trying to push to git server in invoke this script, I get the following message:

*remote: hooks/post-receive: 10: hooks/post-receive: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")*

When I try to run it in command-line, the script works correctly without this message.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Elyashiv

Comment: And what `files_to_notify=( $files_to_notify )`is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to the top of the script to ensure the script is run by `bash` and not `sh`, since you use an array, a `bash` extension.
2. Stop using the array, since you don't use it in any way that couldn't easily be replaced with a simple space-delimited string. That's how you are building the array in the first place.